# Solving Linear Program involving Matrix Variables

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab to solve a Linear program which involves 3 dimensional matrices with entries X(a,b,c). Each Linear inequality/equalities involves multiple pages of the matrix X. 
I can always convert X into a vector, and modify the objective function and inequalities/equalities appropriately, however this is too cumbersome. Is there some simpler way to do this?It will be of enormous help.

I am trying to solve an LP in which the variables are conveniently represented as a 3D matrix, say X(i,j,k). So I am trying to solve

$\max \sum_{i,j,k} X(i,j,k)A(i,j,k)$

$s.t. B*X(:,:,k) =C*X(:,:,k+1),\forall k$

Comment: This really isn't a mathematics question, it's a MATLAB question.

Comment: yes, its a matlab question, I have tagged it as matlab...do I need to post it to some other forum? Please let me know if I got it wrong

Comment: No, contrary to the popular opinion here MATLAB questions are on topic, as defined in [the help center.](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Fair enough, I stand corrected

Comment: @MichaelGrant , I have changed the tag so it is now only matlab.

Comment: @rahul_88 I do not understand what you're trying to do, can you provide some code? As matlab-questions are not really that popular here you might alternatively want to ask at our sister site stackoverflow.com

Comment: @flawr I am trying to solve an LP in which the variables are conveniently represented as a 3D matrix, say X(i,j,k). So I am trying to solve

$\max \sum_{i,j,k} X(i,j,k)A(i,j,k)$ 

$s.t. B*X(:,:,k) =C*X(:,:,k+1),\forall k$